# babel-preset-env SyntaxError: Unexpected token with spread properties

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

[image]

Why its not accepting **spread properties** ? I am using **babel-preset-env** for this.

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {},
                "debug": true,
                "modules": "commonjs"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "",
    "build": "webpack"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Object rest spread`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) operator will *probably* be a **future feature of an ECMAScript specification** (it's in stage 3 for the moment).

For now, it can be supported thanks to `Babel` but you have to use the [`transform-object-rest-spread plugin`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {},
                "debug": true,
                "modules": "commonjs"
            }
        ],
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

Comment: just a doub't ,i am using babel-preset-env ..this library should have imported  (spread operator library) right ?

Comment: Seems like it doesn't because it's still a stage feature: https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/49

Comment: It won't be an ES7 feature because ES7 (ES2016) was already released date last year ;)

Comment: ES8 has already been released as well. Also ESxxxx is the official way if referring to versions now. So, it may be ES2018 but who knows. Does it's matter? The only important part is that it is not part of the spec yet.