# Babel 6 presets not working with Firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm trying to use the spread operator in my firebase function and it's not working.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "case": "^1.5.3",
    "change-case": "^3.0.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "emailjs": "^1.0.12",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

featured.js:

```
"use strict";
const moment = require("moment");

const genDateWithStatus = (startDate, endDate) => ({
  startDate: moment(startDate).valueOf(),
  endDate: moment(endDate).valueOf(),
  status: moment(startDate).valueOf() > moment().valueOf()
    ? "upcoming"
    : moment(endDate).valueOf() > moment().valueOf() ? "active" : "recent"
});

module.exports = [
  {
    url: "https://blah.io/",
    ...genDateWithStatus("11/06/2017", "12/06/2017") // <---------- this part fails
  },
];
```

This is the error that shows up when I try to start my server

```
/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/myapp/functions/src/config/featured.js:19
    ...genDateWithStatus("11/06/2017", "12/06/2017")
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
```

Comment: Please show us your `.babelrc`.

Comment: I have the config in my package.json file, which I pasted above. Babel's docs says it's the same https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

Comment: Oh, true, sorry. Simply including `env` preset isn't enough. You need to specify the target platform versions explicitly: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/. Object spread operator is currently supported neither in Node 8 nor in browsers.

Comment: What value should I put instead of env?

Comment: The problem with "env" plugin is that there's seemingly no way you can make it support object spread operator. I added a proper answer with two possible solutions, so please feel free to use any of those.

Comment: In fact, this Q&A might be considered duplicate, because there's already one that discusses exactly this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796082/babel-preset-env-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-with-spread-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object spread operator is currently (November 2017) not supported in Node and browsers, so you could either use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) syntax

```
module.exports = [
  Object.assign({}, { url: "https://blah.io/" }, genDateWithStatus("11/06/2017", "12/06/2017")),
];
```

or add the [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) transform plugin explicitly.

On the latter, see also Github issue: https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/49.